# What do these colorful triangles mean?

Tags: lateral-thinking

The following picture shows an arrangement of colored triangles.  What is their meaning?

[image: Colorful triangles]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They represent

> The colours of the flags of the G20 nations, displayed in alphabetical order.

Specifically in order from left to right,

> Argentina, Australia, Brazil, Canada, China, European Union, France, Germany, India, Indonesia, Italy, Japan, Republic of Korea, Mexico, Russia, Saudi Arabia, South Africa, Turkey, the United Kingdom, the United States

Comment: It would probably help thus answer to identify which ones are which countries.

Comment: @warspyking They're in alphabetical order, I think.

Comment: @Len, Thanks len, my subconscious recognized the different colours as flag colours, and when I counted I got 20 and thus I figured.  Thanks for the great puzzle I enjoy ones like this.

Comment: @Mew hope you don't mind this version